# ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here in "config.yaml"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I want to configure a yaml file for all project configuration, but this below file I am not able to read/parse it?

Here is the error I am getting, What am I doing wrong here?

```
ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "config.yaml", line 7, column 13
```

---

```
appName: test
logLevel: WARN


TESTER:
    ENVIRONMENT: staging
      CONFIG:
        DATABASE:
          HOST: 2123.3123.2112.12
          USERNAME: x
          PASSWORD: y
          DB: Q
        CLASSIFIER:
          IMG_WIDTH: 380
          IMG_HEIGHT: 380
          HOST: 0.0.0.0:3201
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue is with the indentation of your yaml. `ENVIRONMENT` is having different indent compared to `CONFIG`, which is in next line.

You can use any online validators like http://www.yamllint.com or https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator to validate your yaml files.

This is valid YAML:

```
appName: test
logLevel: WARN


TESTER:
    ENVIRONMENT: staging
    CONFIG:
        DATABASE:
            HOST: 2123.3123.2112.12
            USERNAME: x
            PASSWORD: y
            DB: Q
        CLASSIFIER:
            IMG_WIDTH: 380
            IMG_HEIGHT: 380
            HOST: 0.0.0.0:3201
```

**UPDATE:** 
If you want to use *multiple configurations*, then generally *list of maps* is used with a name attribute like below.

It is a *good practice to give NAME attribute*, even if there is only one config.

```
appName: test
logLevel: WARN

TESTER:
  - NAME: staging
    ENVIRONMENT: staging
    CONFIG:
      DATABASE:
        HOST: 2123.3123.2112.12
        USERNAME: x
        PASSWORD: 'y'
        DB: Q
      CLASSIFIER:
        IMG_WIDTH: 380
        IMG_HEIGHT: 380
        HOST: '0.0.0.0:3201'
  - NAME: production
    ENVIRONMENT: production
    CONFIG:
      DATABASE:
        HOST: 2123.3123.2112.14
        USERNAME: xP
        PASSWORD: yP
        DB: Q
      CLASSIFIER:
        IMG_WIDTH: 380
        IMG_HEIGHT: 380
        HOST: '0.0.0.0:3201'
```

In [this YAML](https://github.com/lyft/pydruid_DEPRECATED/blob/lyft/manifest.yaml), he similarly uses two maps under `deploy`

Comment: I want config to be inside staging environment, because I also have production environment and I want to separate them both, Production env has different database credentails.

Comment: Then there is a mistake in the format you are using, The `CONFIG` should be value of another key, or `CONFIG` should be key by itself. You simply cant increase indent for `CONFIG` under Environment, as the `ENVIRONMENT` has a value and that entry is completed, next extry start with another key: value pair, thats why your YAML is not valid

Comment: can you suggest how to create another (key, value) environment production and use different database information? Can you edit and update it if possible?